# HTTP stack in C

Tags: c, http

Are there any HTTP protocol stacks implemented in C?

Thanks in advance.

Update: looking for client implementations.

Comment: I predict the answer to this question is 'yes'.

Answer (score 11):

You didn't say whether you're looking for client or server, but a quick google turned up [libmicrohttp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) for embedding an HTTP server in your app, and of course [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) for client-side stuff.

**Edit** In answer to your update, definitely libcurl is the answer. I've used it in the past and it's got about every feature you can imagine underneath a fairly easy-to-use interface.

Answer (score 4):

[Libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and [libsoup](http://live.gnome.org/LibSoup) are two client/server side open source http stacks.

Warning : libsoup doesnt have enough documentation. However theres always SO if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [nginx](http://nginx.org/), etc. etc. are all in C, but take a look at [`libevent`](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/doxygen-1.4.10/).

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Serf](http://code.google.com/p/serf/) - used by Subversion and built on top of the Apache Portable Runtime.

Comment: I don't see any documentation online, is it documented in RTFS style?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), it support a large number of protocols, including HTTP. Also, it's well documented, and is quite simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows world, there's also WinInet for client.